# How can I pass a defined dictionary to **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, keyword-argument

I learned how to pass both `**kwargs` and `*args` into a function, and it worked pretty well, like the following:

```py
def market_prices(name, **kwargs):
     print("Hello! Welcome to "+name+" Market!")
     for fruit, price in kwargs.items():
         price_list = " {} is NTD {} per piece.".format(fruit,price)
         print (price_list) 
market_prices('Wellcome',banana=8, apple=10)
```

However in real case, I'd rather pre-defined a dictionary with lots of key&value, so I won't don't have to type in every parameter when calling my function. I have searched online but cannot find a good example or explanation: Here is the code I try to utilize:

```py
fruits:{"apple":10,
       "banana":8,
       "pineapple":50,
       "mango":45
       }

def market_prices(name, **fruits):
    print("Hello! Welcome to "+name+" Market!")
    for fruit, price in fruits.items():
        price_list = " {} is NTD {} per piece.".format(fruit,price)
        print (price_list)
```

```
>>> market_prices('Wellcome ', fruits)

NameError: name 'fruits' is not defined
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are 4 possible cases:

You call the function using **named arguments** and you want **named variables** in the function:
(note the default values)

```
def buy(orange=2, apple=3):
    print('orange: ', orange)
    print('apple: ', apple)

buy(apple=4)
# orange:  2
# apple:  4
```

You call the function using **named arguments** but you want **a dictionary** in the function:
then use `**dictionaryname` in the function definition to collect the passed arguments

```
def buy(**shoppinglist):
    for name, qty in shoppinglist.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, qty) )

buy(apple=4, banana=5)
# banana: 5
# apple: 4
```

You call the function passing **a dictionary** but you want **named variables** in the function:
use `**dictionaryname` when calling the function to unpack the dictionary

```
def buy(icecream=1, apple=3, egg=1):
    print('icecream:', icecream)
    print('apple:', apple)
    print('egg:', egg)

shoppinglist = {'icecream':5, 'apple':1}
buy(**shoppinglist)
# icecream: 5
# apple: 1
# egg: 1
```

You call the function passing **a dictionary** and you want **a dictionary** in the function:
just pass the dictionary

```
def buy(shoppinglist):
    for name, qty in shoppinglist.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, qty) )

shoppinglist = {'egg':45, 'apple':1}
buy(shoppinglist)
# egg: 45
# apple: 1
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `**` before fruits argument.

```
fruits={"apple":10,
       "banana":8,
       "pineapple":50,
       "mango":45
       }

def market_prices(name, **fruits):
    print("Hello! Welcome to "+name+" Market!")
    for fruit, price in fruits.items():
        price_list = " {} is NTD {} per piece.".format(fruit,price)
        print (price_list)

market_prices('Wellcome ', **fruits) #Use **before arguments
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, in most cases you will see something like `def market_place(name,**kwargs):` that you use like `market_place('La Cebada',**fruits)`  (PS: La Cebada is one of the historical markets in Madrid ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

Acknowledgments to you guys for the quick and useful comments!

While defining a function, if you put `**` for your argument, then make sure to put it too when calling it! Otherwise, put neither!

1. With `**`

   ```py
   fruits={"apple":10,
          "banana":8,
          "pineapple":50,
          "mango":45
          }

       def market_prices(name, **fruits):
           print("Hello! Welcome to "+name+" Market!")
           for fruit, price in fruits.items():
               price_list = " {} is NTD {} per piece.".format(fruit,price)
               print (price_list)

       market_prices('Wellcome ', **fruits)
   ```
2. Without `**`

   ```py
   fruits={"apple":10,
          "banana":8,
          "pineapple":50,
          "mango":45
          }

       def market_prices(name, fruits):
           print("Hello! Welcome to "+name+" Market!")
           for fruit, price in fruits.items():
               price_list = " {} is NTD {} per piece.".format(fruit,price)
               print (price_list)

       market_prices('Wellcome ', fruits)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo defining `fruits`. It should have been like the following

```
fruits = {"apple":10,
       "banana":8,
       "pineapple":50,
       "mango":45
       }
```

Comment: Note that prior to Python 3.6, this would have shown up as a syntax error. Now, it's just an odd-looking variable annotation.