# How do you take multiple named parameters in a function and pass them to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, named-parameters

One of the coolest things I've learned about python recently is that a dictionary can take parameters like this:

```
dict(red=3,blue=2,yellow=5)
```

How could I make a function that takes arguments in the same fashion and pass them to a dictionary? I don't want to declare red, blue, or yellow as individual parameters. Ideally, this would take in named parameters of any kind.

I've already tried:

```
def foo(*args):
```

...and it doesn't like how the parameters are named.

Another thought I had was extending the dictionary definition so I could still use **init** of the dictionary, but I wouldn't know how to do that either.

Comment: Try `**kwargs`. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751929/python-can-i-pass-a-defined-dictionary-to-kwargs

Comment: have you tried `def foo(**kwargs):`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with `*args`, but what I think you want to use is `**kwargs`.

```py
def make_dict(**kwargs):
    return dict(**kwargs)

myDict = make_dict(red=2, cyan=43)
print(myDict)
```

it should print `{'red': 2, 'cyan': 43}`